# Problem install libraries R Debian 10. How install bigrquery and tidyverse

Tags: r, linux, debian

I'm new  working with Debian 10 in Google jupyter notebooks. When I'll want to install library bigrquery or tidyverse I do have problems. i was tried to install libcurl4-openssl-dev  `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`  However these libraries (bigrquery and tidyverse) do not work.

**My versions:**

1. R: 4.0.5
2. libcurl4: libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version (7.64.0-4+deb10u2)
3. Linux: Debian 10 Google Jupyter notebook AI platafform
4. Conda 4.10.3

Plase help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLKW2.jpg)

Comment: Did the `apt-get` install command complete without error?

Comment: yes, the version install is libcurl4-openssl-dev  (7.64.0-4 + deb10u2)  is already the newest version

Comment: Okay, what does `Sys.which("pkg-config")` return?